# Why is Recipe used in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

What is the purpose of installing recipe and the difference between using recipe and without using recipe in *hybris*?
I don't have wiki access so can anyone please explain. Thanks in advance

Comment: If any links are there where I can get recipe information please share.I have some doubts regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recipe helps the process of automating the things. Suppose you are looking for b2c flavor of hybris commerce then you can use b2c_acc on 6.0 it will have all the required extension for b2c. Also if you want to setup some config details you can use it. for more details you can follow help.hybris.com.

Comment: Actually I don't have access to Hybris.com .Can please provide some more information

Comment: Do you have hybris commerce if yes go to hybris/installer/recipe/<any recipe>/build.gradle if you will see the file all the required extension for particular type is described on that. it is gradle script.

Comment: And this is different from an accelerator?

Answer (score 2):

Hybris came up with this concept of **recipe for automatic installation**.
It is a **gradle file**, It will take care of installing all required extensions.

Depending on your requirement you can choose you recipe, There are more than 24 recipe (version 6.3) available.

If you want **b2b** accelerator you can go for **b2b_acc**

telco - **b2c_telco**

china - **b2c_china**

Or if you want to build everything from scratch you can go for **platform_only**

Answer (score 0):

Recipes are used to add required extensions to the hybris platform. For example, if you want to install the recipe 'b2c_acc', call the command 'install.bat -r b2c_acc'. This command go to the **{HYBRIS_HOME}**\installer\recipes\b2c_acc, and read the build.gradle file located in this folder.

When you open build.gradle file, you can see all the extensions that are required for this recipe. If there is no recipe concept, you must install all these extensions manually, but with recipes, you automated this manual installation.

Reference
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/explore-power-recipes-sap-hybris-commerce-muhammad-haris-ahmed/